# R plot adding points error

Tags: r, plot

I have a vector x and a vector y in which plot(x, y) works perfectly fine. However, i realized that for my application I would like to add a finite list of specific points (x1, y1)....(xn, yn) to this plot. To produce this, I used:

```
a = c(x1, ....., xn)
b = c(y1, ....., yn)
plot(c(x, a), c(y, b))
```

However I got the following graph: [image: Wrong Graph]

You can see the connecting of the last endpoint with which i guess is one of the points I added. Does anyone know why this is happening? I also tried putting both x and y in a data frame and then sorting by x to try to remove this, but haven't had any luck.

EDIT:

---

Putting the two vectors into a data frame and then sorting by x DOES work. In my case, I was doing this all in a function, and assigned the sorted x and y to the global frame in case plot had failed. This caused the function to use the old environment values which was giving my error.

Comment: What was so unlucky about sorting them in a data.frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
plot(x, y, col = "red", xlim = range(c(x, a)), ylim = range(c(y, b)))
lines(sort(a), b[order(a)], col = "blue")
```